# Svg object modified with setAttributeNS not updating until after while loop

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm creating a small game in javascript and I'm using svg for the graphics. Right now I'm having a problem with updating the game in the middle of a game tick. If I exit my loop directly after I update the fill attribute with "setAttributeNS", it's redrawn, but if I don't do that, it isn't updated until after "game_tick" is over. Even worse, if I call "game_tick" multiple times in a row, the svg objects aren't updated until after I've run all of the "game_tick"s instead of being updated after each one.

```
function game_tick(){
            num_grid_copy = num_grid.slice();
            for (var x = 0; x < num_squares_x; x += 1) {    
                for (var y = 0; y < num_squares_x; y += 1) { 
                    var n = get_neighbors(x,y);
                    var isAliveInNextGen = next_gen(n, num_grid[x*num_squares_x+y]);
                    num_grid_copy[x*num_squares_x+y] =  isAliveInNextGen;
                    if (isAliveInNextGen == 1){
                        rect_grid[x*num_squares_x+y].setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#0099ff');
                    }
                    else {
                        rect_grid[x*num_squares_x+y].setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#fff');
                    }
                }
            }
            num_grid = num_grid_copy;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that's how javascript works.

Comment: Why is it not possible to update the screen within a while loop? For clarification, I'm wrapping game_tick in a while loop and running it over and over. I don't expect the screen to update in the middle of game tick. I would've thought the screen would update after the function finished, even if i decided to run game tick multiple times in a row.

Comment: Because updates only occur when your code isn't running.

Comment: Ahh thanks Robert, I think I can fix this then. I'll save the grid and update the screen afterwards. I could also use window.setInterval as well I think?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to valuable input from Robert I realized that javascript execution and page rendering are done in the same thread. I changed the function to the following:

```
function start() {
            var inc = 0,
            max = 25;
            delay = 100; // 100 milliseconds

            var repeat = setInterval(function() {

                game_tick();
                if (++inc >= max)
                    clearInterval(repeat);
                },
            delay);
            }
```

This works fine. I can set the delay and the number of times it repeats.